# ConcurrentHashMap, find by value, compare fields and put

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

How can I check if there is a value using the fields of a given value? And put new one?
In ConcurrentHashMap, cause I have N threads.

Here is an example of what I want. However, it is not thread-safe.

```
Map<Integer, Record> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

// it works, but I think it's unsafe
int get(Object key) {
   for (Map.Entry<Integer, Record> next : map.entrySet()) {
        if (next.getValue().a == key) {
          return next.getValue().b;
        }
      }
    int code = ...newCode();
    map.put(code, new Record(...))
    return code;
}

record Record(Object a, int b) {
}
```

Comment: Technically, I can use my locks and the classic hashmap, but as far as I know, it's not very productive.

Comment: yeah, but... Map is <Integer, ?> and I can't just use #computeIfAbsent(Object from Record)

Comment: Wait, Never mind. I wasn't looking closely enough at what you are trying to do. I have withdrawn my previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

What you're suggesting would defeat the purpose of using a HashMap since you're iterating through the Map instead of retrieving from the Map.

What you should really do is create a new Map where the field in Record.a is the Key and the field in Record.B is the value (or just the whole Record). Then just update your logic to insert into both Maps appropriately.

Comment: Oh, thanks, you helped me look at the problem from a different angle. 
However, sometimes I need to search by Record.b, which again forces me to search by field from the value. Or maybe two Maps... I will try and indicate in the question if necessary.